# Struct and MemoryView Module Equivalents in Julia

Tags: python, julia

I am trying to convert some code from Python to Julia. The python code uses the `struct` function and `memoryview` module. Is there an equivalent in Julia that can be used?

Comment: Do you mean https://github.com/JuliaIO/ProtoBuf.jl ?

Answer (score 1):

While I am not familiar with these python modules, if my quick search as to their purpose is correct, they are not applicable / necessary in Julia because Julia `structs` are by default already mutually interoperable with C (ex: [[1]](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/#Struct-Type-Correspondences),[[2]](https://michaellindon.github.io/lindonslog/programming/passing-julia-type-to-c-function-as-struct/)) and Julia objects such as `String`s, `Array`s (including `Array`s of well-behaved `struct`s), etc., are already merely views of memory plus some metadata. For example:

```
julia> A = fill(NaN,5)
5-element Vector{Float64}:
 NaN
 NaN
 NaN
 NaN
 NaN

julia> reinterpret(Int64,A) # With no overhead, interpret the same block of memory as a different type
5-element reinterpret(Int64, ::Vector{Float64}):
 9221120237041090560
 9221120237041090560
 9221120237041090560
 9221120237041090560
 9221120237041090560

julia> Ref(A) # Julia-style pointer
Base.RefValue{Vector{Float64}}([NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN])

julia> Base.pointer(A) # Native pointer
Ptr{Float64} @0x000000011e52c7d0
```

[1] https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/#Struct-Type-Correspondences

[2] https://michaellindon.github.io/lindonslog/programming/passing-julia-type-to-c-function-as-struct/